# average data according to the ID distribution of different columns

Tags: r

I have a `data.frame`, I would like to average the column `data` according to `ID,M1,M2,M3`. 
Aggregated does the job pretty well but it discriminate when exactly the same ID (e.g. `10`) is located in a different column.

```
ID<-c(rep("A", times=10), rep("B", times=10))
data<-21:40
M1<-c("","10","10","10",  "",  "", "10","20", "10","", "","11","11","11",  "",  "", "10","11", "11","")
M2<-c("", "", "10","10","10",  "",  "", "10", "20","", "", "", "11","11","11",  "",  "", "11", "21","")
M3<-c("", "",  "", "10","10","10",  "",  "",   "", "", "", "",  "", "11","11","11",  "",  "",   "", "")
df<-data.frame(ID, M1, M2, M3, data)
aggregate(data ~ ID + M1 + M2 + M3 , df , mean)
```

Instead, I would like to aggregate rows with the same `ID` and when it occurs similarly among `M1` or `M2` or `M3` columns, without discriminating the column position. For example in the `data.frame` below the column data should be averaged from rows 2 and 3 averages as well as rows 5 and 6 average data. I would like to use apply functions if possible

```
   ID M1 M2 M3 data
1   A            21
2   A 10         22
3   A 10         23
4   A 10 10 10   24 
5   A 10 20      28 
6   A 20 10      29
```

Comment: It would be easy group your data with `dplyr`: `df %>% group_by(ID)`

Comment: But I have to consider M1, M2, M3 as well

Comment: You say `"column data should be averaged from rows 2 and 3 averages"`, why not row 4 as well? It also contains `"10"`.

Comment: I would like to average the column `data`  according to `ID,M1,M2, M3`. Row 4 has 3 time 10 while rows 5 and 6 have bot 10 and 20 so they have common IDs across `M1 M2 M3`

Comment: your data/code sample from above does not produce the output you show. can you re-check what is wrong?

Comment: That's not an output it is an example

Comment: Could you specify more how you would like to average? Is it the number of "10"s in the M1, M2, M3 rows,? what about row 5, would it then occure again in an average considering the 20's ? Can you share an expected output?

Comment: `M1 M2 M3` are tags like `ID` to be considered when `data` are averaged

Comment: This is was your call to aggregate does. If you need something different please share your expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that this depends on what you will want to do with the results afterwards. If you don't mind introducing a new variable, you can do the following (which is basically the same as Captain Stone's answer but without data.table and with apply):

```
df[["group"]] <- apply(df[, -5], 1, paste0, collapse = '')
> head(df)
  ID M1 M2 M3 data   group
1  A            21       A
2  A 10         22     A10
3  A 10 10      23   A1010
4  A 10 10 10   24 A101010
5  A    10 10   25   A1010
6  A       10   26     A10
```

Then you can simply use the new variable:

```
> aggregate(data ~ ID + group , df , mean)                                                                                                                                                                     
   ID   group     data
1   A       A 25.50000
2   A     A10 25.00000
3   A   A1010 25.33333
4   A A101010 24.00000
5   A   A1020 29.00000
6   B       B 35.50000
7   B     B10 37.00000
8   B     B11 34.00000
9   B   B1111 35.33333
10  B B111111 34.00000
11  B   B1121 39.00000
```

Comment: Good answer. I just have a habit to recommend the data.table package everywhere for it's improved speed and memory usage.

Comment: Thanks. Absolutely, I'm basically living inside data.table's "j" for most of my work

Answer (score 2):

I'm still unsure what you are looking for, but here is one operation that might help you...

If you want to keep unique tag combinations regardless of their column:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(ID, M1, M2, M3, data)
dt[, uniq := apply(dt, 1, function(r) paste(unique(r[1:4]), collapse = ''))]
dt[, mean(data), by = uniq]
```

from this you get:

```
    uniq       V1
1:     A 25.50000
2:   A10 25.00000
3: A1020 29.00000
4:     B 35.50000
5:   B11 34.66667
6:   B10 37.00000
7: B1121 39.00000
```

Comment: Modifying the `function(r)` gives you different possible ways to group.

Answer (score 0):

Is it what you expect ?

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
col_names <- setdiff(names(df), 'ID')

## convert data types to integer
for(i in col_names)
    set(x = df, j=i, value = ifelse(df[[i]] == '', 0, as.integer(as.character(df[[i]]))))

# find mean
df[,lapply(.SD, mean),ID]

   ID  M1  M2  M3 data
1:  A 6.0 6.0 3.0 25.5
2:  B 6.5 6.5 3.3 35.5
```

Comment: This is not what I am looking for, `M1 M2 M3` should not be averaged, they are a tag to be considered for `data` grouping average.

Comment: Difficult to understand. Please provide an output table.